# Wand: Image.composite turns bg-image black

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand, magickwand

I have a problem. The following code does work and it combines the two images. But the background-image in the final composing is completely black.

Any guesses, what's the problem here?

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename=bgimage) as back:
    with Image(filename=qrcode) as front:
        with Image(width=back.width, height=back.height) as new_image:
            new_image.composite(front, left=1000, top=900)
            new_image.save(filename=qr_output)
```

Comment: The background of `new_image` is defined to "none", and so the finial image should have a black background. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `new_image` section, and simplify everything.

```py
with Image(filename="wizard:") as back:
  with Image(filename="rose:") as front:
    back.composite(front,
                   top=back.height-front.height,
                   left=back.width-front.width)
    back.save(filename="/tmp/output.png")
```

[image: output.png]

If your attempting to reuse `back` instance, then leverage `wand.image.Image.clone`

```py
with Image(filename=bgimage) as back:
  with Image(filename=qrcode) as front:
     with back.clone() as new_image:
       new_image.composite(front, left=1000, top=900)
       new_image.save(filename=qr_output)
```

Comment: Works! Great! Thank you!